# laravel cpanal smtp Connection could not be established with host "ssl://live.smtp.mailtrap.io:465":

Tags: php, email, smtp, laravel-9

Connection could not be established with host "ssl://live.smtp.mailtrap.io:465"  not work in  cpanal only
tested in mailtrap/zoho/ send mail geting same errror
smtp port open varified in cpanal zoho edc..

my config
`MAIL_MAILER=smtp MAIL_HOST=smtp.zoho.com MAIL_PORT=587/645/587 MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls/ssl MAIL_USERNAME=MAIL_PASSWORD=MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS= MAIL_FROM_NAME`